# Input type=file shows incorrect in IE8-9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a big project and many css styles. And I have input file type that shows incorrect in ie8 and ie9. I just see background-color and text "Browse...". So, when I exclude border from style using development tools in IE ... it shows correct. But I can't remove border using js or css. When I set default value: border: medium none #000 it doesn't work. Maybe it inherited style. How I can remove border-style from input-element.

Has anyone had this problem? I need default button for input-file control. How I can use js (jQuery) or css?  IE has native style for elements?

HTML:

```
<input name="ImportFileInp$InputField" class="cs-fileinput" id="ImportFileInp_InputField"           type="file"/>
```

CSS:

```
.cs-fileinput {
    width: 71px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

but in browser i see: border: 0px none currentColor

Comment: Can you show your problem in **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**? As for me, there is no problem with `borders` if to just use the code you provided in the question. Thus, assuming that you have some additional `css` or `javascript` which overrides the style of your `input`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L6VLC/

look like this. See it in IE8 (or IE9) and FF.

Comment: I tried to do so http://jsfiddle.net/L6VLC/2/

Comment: That way the button just cuts off at the middle?

Comment: It does not matter. Button shows incorrect in IE8-9. Can set more width. http://jsfiddle.net/L6VLC/5/

Comment: You should do something like **[Customize your upload button](http://jsfiddle.net/28x7Y/369/)** - Because each browser has different style for `<input type="file" />` this is not only IE issue.

Comment: @ValYar. You are welcome. Also, I have moved my suggestion into answers, so if it resolved your issue, please mark it as correct one then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In accordance to our discussion, you should **[Customize your upload button](http://jsfiddle.net/28x7Y/369/)**. 
The issue is not only in IE browser. Each browser has a different style (own style) for `<input type="file" />` button.
Here is some example of how you can customize your upload button: 
**HTML code**

```
<div class="custom-upload">
  <input type="file">
  <div class="fake-file">
      <input disabled="disabled" >
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-upload {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 350px;
  margin:30px;
}

.custom-upload input[type=file] {
  outline:none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;    
  -moz-opacity:0 ;
  filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;  
}

.custom-upload .fake-file {
  background:url(http://www.fold3.com/i/upload-icon.png) center right no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.custom-upload .fake-file input {
  font-size:16px;
  height:40px;
  width:300px;
}
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
$('.custom-upload input[type=file]').change(function(){
  $(this).next().find('input').val($(this).val());
});
```

Thus, you can just change backgroung in `.custom-upload .fake-file` class to whatever image you want and it will have the same view in all browsers.